# Filtering and printing in python

Tags: python

How can I print like this:

```
Player: 4D, 4S, JH, 9D, 3C   
Banker: 6C, 3C, 7H, 6S, 2H
```

And how can I remove the lowest and highest in the list of their cards?

```
import random

card_value = []
suits = ["H", "D", "C", "S"]
royals = ["J", "Q", "K", "A"]
deck = []

for i in range(2, 11):
    card_value.append(str(i))

for j in range(4):
    card_value.append(royals[j])

for k in range(4):
    for l in range(13):
        card = (card_value[l] + suits[k])
        deck.append(card)
random.shuffle(deck)

for m in range(5):
    print "Player:", deck[m]
  
for o in range(5):
    print "Banker:", deck[o]
```

Comment: What is a card? and what is the highest?

Comment: The highest is K (King) while the lowest is A (Ace)

Answer (score 1):

I won't give you the exact solution, but some pointers for you to look at. I do this because it's not clear what problem you're walking into exactly.

The for loop prints `"Player:"` on every iteration. The solution would be to put that *outside* of the loop. In the `print` call, use `end=","` to make sure it doesn't print on a new line.

Also, please please *please*, don't use `i, j, k, l, m, o` as variable names. It's unreadable like this. Instead, use `value, suit, card_idx` or similar variables so that we (and you, later on) can immediately understand what's going on.

By the way, there's one bug: the Player and the Banker get the same cards now, because the cards are not removed from the deck after dealing them. Tip: use `card = deck.pop()` to remove a card from the `deck` list and save it in the `card` variable. Then you can for example use `player_cards.append(card)` to deal the card to the player.